# Apache RewriteRule on URL with query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a URL with a query string using the .htaccess file.

The actual value in the query string is not important.

I need to send `/event/event.php?t=2` to `/event/challenge`

How can I do this?

I've tried the following but no joy:

```
RewriteRule ^event/event.php?t=2$ /event/challenge [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+event/event\.php?t=2[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /event/challenge? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^event/challenge/?$ /event/event.php?t=2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Yes that is what this rule does. `?` after `/event/challenge` strips off any existing query string.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a RewriteCond before rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=2
RewriteRule ^event/event.php$ /event/challenge [L,QSA,NC]
```